# how to replace in php replace ½ with .5

Tags: php, utf-8, preg-replace, str-replace

how to replace special character ½ with .5 in a string 7½. i want to output string as 7.5

```
preg_replace('/\x{EF}\x{BF}\x{BD}/u', '.5', iconv(mb_detect_encoding($str), 'UTF-8', $str));
```

is not replacing to .5

Comment: did you check if the regex actually matches? e.g. `preg_match('/x...../'` should return a TRUE if the regex is correct.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried:

```
$str = "how to replace special character ½ with .5 in a string 7½. i want to output string as 7.5";
echo preg_replace('/½/u', '.5', iconv(mb_detect_encoding($str), 'UTF-8', $str));
//or
echo preg_replace('/½/u', '.5', $str);
//or
echo preg_replace('/½/', '.5', $str);
```

Comment: @user1812318: All these 3 solutions work fine for me.

Comment: could it be that your editor needs to have its settings changed? what are you using?

Answer (score 0):

str_replace is faster, than preg_replace, and also does the trick

```
$str = "how to replace special character ½ with .5 in a string 7½. i want to output string as 7.5";

echo str_replace('½', '.5', $str);
```

Comment: str_replace function works for only UTF-8 characters. ½ is a non -ytf encoded character.